# Visual Studio Snippets: How to reference an assembly that is not in the GAC

Tags: .net, xml, assemblies, reference, code-snippets

I have a 3rd party non-signed assembly that I want to reference in several projects.
So I created a snippet to add the reference and the relative imports

I tried the following, and several variations with full paths, without file:// etc, to no avail.
Any ideas?

```
...
<Snippet>
    <References>
        <Reference>
            <Assembly>MyAssemly.dll</Assembly>
            <Url>file://C:\Program Files\MyProduct</Url>
        </Reference>
    </References>
    <Imports>
        <Import>
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No happy answers here.  The URL element is there only for F1 help.  The Assembly element must be a simple name or a fully qualified assembly name.

The bigger obstacle is that the `<Reference>` element still has not been implemented in the C# IDE.  It is the subject of this old [feedback item](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/91062/need-references-element-to-be-supported-in-c-snippets).  It is closed as "Postponed" which offers some hope that this will actually work some day.  They may actually make absolute path names work.

Add your vote to the feedback item, they *do* pay attention to that.

Answer (score 0):

Local references can be made by adding reference and browsing to the assembly location.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I wasnt to do that *in a snippet* definition though.